# how to install local node_modules into global and access it with cli by environment variable

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I had a package named `g-pc` that extend from Yeoman,I had link it to global by `npm link`,but i don't know how to access it with cli by environment variable

for example:

1. cd ~/g-pc
2. npm link
3. cd ~/`some other path`
4. run `g-pc --help` in cli  (this is what i want)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to link g-pc before calling it?

cd ~/g-pc

npm link

cd ~/some other path

**npm link g-pc**

run g-pc --help in cli

You have to be sure that g-pc is the project name of your dependency.

Other configuration that is necessary it is to place the property bin in package.json:

```
...
"bin": {
    "g-pc": "./index.js"
}
...
```

Comment: yes,because i had run npm link in g-pc folder,i'm sure it is a symbolic link in C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\g-pc

Comment: Got it. You can try unlink too, to give another try. Npm unlink --no-save g-pc in some other path and npm unlink on g-pc folder. After that try to repeat the link.

Answer (score 0):

because i forget to set `bin` field of package.json